# How to display initialValues for material-ui autocomplete field?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I use the autocomplete field of material-ui (v5) and formik to generate my forms.
On this form, I have some lists defined as constants.

I use an api to get the default value of this list.
This api returns only the "code" of the option but not its label.

```js
<Formik
        enableReinitialize
        initialValues={initialFormValues}
        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
[...]
<Autocomplete
  error={Boolean(touched.civility && errors.civility)}
  helperText={touched.civility && errors.civility}
  label="Civility"
  margin="normal"
  name="civility"
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue('civility', value)}
  options={civilities}
  value={values.civility}
  getOptionLabel={(option) =>
    option.name ? option.name : ''
  }
  isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.code === value}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="outlined"
      label={<Trans>Civility</Trans>}
    />
  )}
/>
```

My parameter isOptionEqualToValue is good because even if the value is not displayed in the input, it is well selected in the list.

You can see that the input text field is empty:

[image: field empty]

But if I unroll the list, I can see that my "ms" value has been selected:

[image: List ok]

What should I do to make the input text contain the default value?

Answer (score 4):

After cloned your snippet code above, the problem was in `getOptionLabel`, the `option` argument is a string value, so it hasn't a `name` property and appears empty string. Here is an online example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-display-initialvalues-for-material-ui-autocomplete-field-po3k4?file=/src/App.js).

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function App() {
  const civilities = ["Mr", "Ms", "Other"];
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    civility: "Ms"
  });

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    console.log("Blur:", e.target.value);
  };

  const setFieldValue = (type, value) => {
    setValues((oldValues) => ({ ...oldValues, [type]: value }));
  };

  return (
    <Formik err>
      {({ errors, touched }) => (
        <Form>
          <Autocomplete
            error={Boolean(touched.civility && errors.civility)}
            helperText={touched.civility && errors.civility}
            label="Civility"
            margin="normal"
            name="civility"
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue("civility", value)}
            options={civilities}
            value={values.civility}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.code === value}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="Civility" />
            )}
          />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```